# Remoting in flex - Is service-config really needed? And What is endpoint url?

Tags: apache-flex, url, remoting, endpoint

Rather than calling it a question, i would like to call it a discussion and the topic is **Flex Remoting**. Forms and blogs explaining remoting in flex always mention 2 things:

> 1. service-config.xml
> 2. endpoint url

Now what i want to know is that

**1.** *is service-config file actually needed* if we need to bind our front end (which is in flex / air) with some database (mySql for instance). Coz i've done a couple of projects in flex and air and didn't use this config file. I used Flex 3. Though i used this config file in the projects i did in earlier version of flex 2.0 .

**2.** *What actually this endpoint url does*; could someone please explain it.

The way i implement remoting is like this:

```
<mx:RemoteObject id="remoteObj" source="MyPHPCls" destination="AMFPHP" result="remoteResult(event)">

     <mx:method name="someServerSideMethod" result="onMethodResult(event)" />

</mx:RemoteObject>
```

Also if you could please tell me if the approach i am following to use remoting is incorrect.

Hope to hear from someone soon :).

Thnx,
Jatin

Answer (score 2):

The services-config.xml data is compiled, or hard coded, into your application at compile time.  You don't need to use a services-config.xml file if you don't want to; but if you want to use RemoteObject, that data will need to be available to your SWF somehow.

Here is a [good blog post](http://www.mikenimer.com/?p=320) on setting the services-config file at runtime.

The end-point URL is just a URL to a Remoting Gateway.